# how to select elements that not intersec?

Tags: c#, linq, list, where-in

If I have two list and I want the elements that are common in both lists, I can use this code:

```
var listC = listA.Intersect(listB);
```

However, If I want the elements that are not common? And without duplicates? is possible with intersect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, that's possible. It's called [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx).

Use this:

```
var result = listA.Except(listB); //maybe a .ToList() at the end,
//or passing an IEqualityComparer<T> if you want a different equality comparison.
```

Answer (score 3):

Neither answer so far will include items from `listB` that aren't in `listA`. To get *any* item that is in *either* list, but is not in *both* lists:

```
listA.Union(listB).Except(listA.Intersect(listB));
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can also do `listA.Except(listB).Union(listB.Except(listA))`

Comment: +1, it's a better answer than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Most efficient:

```
var set = new HashSet<T>(listA);
set.SymmetricExceptWith(listB);
```